# Some Clients php_session_id not changing over time

Tags: php

We have some code on our PHP Application that logs users PHP Session ID with referal_url etc. We have noticed some clients perpetually use the same php_session_id and for some reason the php_session cookie is not being dropped on the client on expiry time or closing of browser. (End result we are seeing 3 months of application usage under the one session id)

Is this behaviour normal? Is there any way to enforce a new php_session_id server side if php session_id cookie is expired. I also notice the cookie on client side does not have expiry which may fundamentally our problem?

Comment: For what it's worth, PHP does not generate new session IDs for existing sessions. It provides tools to do it, but it doesn't by itself. You typically get new IDs because browser loses track of old IDs when session cookie is gone.

Answer (score 1):

> I also notice the cookie on client side does not have expiry which may fundamentally our problem?

Yes, and No :-)

A cookie without any expiry time specified, is what is considered a "session cookie" - with "session" not referring to the PHP session here, but the user's "browsing session." When the user closes their browser window, the browser is supposed to throw this cookie away.

*But* - modern browsers have mechanisms to "store" a browsing session for future use, and with that, they also preserve those session cookies, and will restore them when the user restores this "browsing session."

To counter that, you could *give* your PHP session ID cookie an expiry time - but the unwanted side effect of that could be, that users who *expected* simply closing the browser would log them out, would still find themselves logged in, if the open the browser again, before the cookie expiry time has passed. Or, this could be a *different* user opening the same browser afterwards on a shared computer ...

Better would be, if you recorded the last access time *in* your session. Then you can check how much time has passed, the next time that session gets picked up - and if that is past your "tolerance interval", you re-generate the session ID, using `session_regenerate_id`.

Then users who simply close their browser will still be logged out as expected; users who store their "browsing session" and access your site with an "old" session ID, would then get a new one assigned at this point.